# What does "mass" actually mean in probability analysis?

Tags: probability-theory

I was reading the textbook for an analytical probability theory subject and it discusses that probability has a "mass character" to it.

My understanding is that this is in reference to the probability mass function, but is there a reason for why we use this kind of terminology to describe it?

Same goes with density - why do we use the terminology density for continuous probability functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability mass function and probability density function are generalized by the notion of a [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure).

Sometimes, one intuitively thinks of a measure as assigning "weight" or "mass" to certain sets. For example, on says that a probability measure has "all its mass in the unit interval", to mean that $\mu([0,1]) = 1$ and $\mu(\mathbb{R} \setminus [0,1]) = 0$.

Similarly, some people talk about "charge". For example, saying that the set $[0,1]$ has uncharged boundary would mean that $\mu(\{0,1\}) = 0$.

Adding to the "mass" interpretation. Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable. Think of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ as a seesaw, pivoted at $0$. Then $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$ precisely when its probability distribution assigns "mass" in such a way that the seesaw is in equilibrium i.e. such that the torque cancels out.

Comment: True, let me rephrase

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense now.